# Summarizing count of multiple talbes in one row or column

Tags: sql-server

I've designed a migration script and as the last sequence, I'm running the following two lines.

```
select count(*) from Origin
select count(*) from Destination
```

However, I'd like to present those numbers as cells in the same table. I haven't decided yet if it's most suitable to put them as separate rows in one column or adjacent columns on one row but I do want them in the same table.

How can I select stuff from those selects into vertical/horizontal line-up?

I've tried *select* on them both with and without parentheses but id didn't work out (probably because of the missing *from*)...

This questions is related to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921226) but differs in two aspects. Firstly, it's much more to-the-point and clearer states the issue. Secondly, it asks about both horizontal and vertical line-up of the selected values whereas the linked questions only regards the former.

```
select 
  select count(*) from Origin,
  select count(*) from Destination

select(
  select count(*) from Origin,
  select count(*) from Destination)
```

Comment: Hmm... Downvoter - care to let me know how to improve the question? I'll be delighted to...

Comment: If you post the code that you tried, we can explain why it didn't work as a learning experience.

Comment: @TabAlleman I've tried adding the word *select* before the two lines and a comma character between them. That's all I could think of. Would you still like me to post the code? Please view the edit...

Comment: The problem with your attempt was that sub-selects need to be in parenthesis (each one in its own parens-set).  It's also a good idea to give them an alias, or they won't have a column name in the result set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join result of two sql statements into one table and different columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921226/how-to-join-result-of-two-sql-statements-into-one-table-and-different-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest the two select statements under a main (top) SELECT in order to get one row with the counts of both tables:

```
SELECT
    (select count(*) from Origin) AS OriginCount,
    (select count(*) from Destination) AS DestinationCount
```

[**SQLFiddle for the above query**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24e29/1)

I hope this is what you are looking for, since the "same table" you are mentioning is slightly confusing. (I'm assuming you're referring to result set)

Alternatively you can use `UNION ALL` to return two cells with the count of both tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 'Origin' 'Table' FROM ORIGIN
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*), 'Destination' 'Table' FROM Destination
```

[**SQLFiddle with UNION ALL**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24e29/5)

[**SQLFiddle with UNION**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24e29/4)

I recommend adding the second text column so that you know the corresponding table for each number.

As opposed to simple `UNION` the `UNION ALL` command will return two rows everytime. The `UNION` command will generate a single result (single cell) if the count of rows in both tables is the same (the same number).

Comment: This answer is both well formulated and complete. You also added links to the fiddles, which should be +2 (I hope someone else win contribute to that as I can only provide you with +1). I also didn't know there where fiddles for SQL, so I learned more than I asked for, so it should be +3, maybe...

Comment: @KonradViltersten Glad it was more than helpful for you!

Comment: Can you, please, check that you still can access the fiddles. I can't do it from my computer. It says "please build schema" etc...

Comment: @KonradViltersten I've just checked the links and they are fine.

Comment: Confirming that they do work correctly **now**. Must have been some weirdification i nthe cyberspace before...

Comment: @KonradViltersten Unfortunately SQLFiddle occasionally has problems.

Answer (score 1):

...or if you want vertical...

```
select 'OriginalCount' as Type,  count(*)
  from origin
union
select 'DestinationCount' as Type,  count(*)
  from destination
```